# XOR reduction bools

Tags: code-golf, string, math

## Description :

Given a string of space separated binary digits or space separated booleans or an array of binary digits or array of booleans . Your job is to find the xor of each until you end up with one answer either 0 or 1. The inputs will always be valid and will only be either 0 or 1.

## Example :

```
1 0 0 1 0 --> 0
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 --> 1
```

This is code golf so shortest code will win. Good luck.

Comment: _Your job is to find the xor of each until you end up with one answer either 0 or 1_ Can you clarify a bit more what that means?

Comment: given a string find the xor of first two then the xor of next two and so on. keep at it till you end with one digit.

Comment: **Use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)!** That's 3 challenges in a row that you propose that have troubles. Go to the sandbox, expose your challenge and update it based on community feedback. Then only post it on this site.

Comment: Hi, I've downvoted this question because it is very trivial. Most answers are going to be one or two variations, with very little room for creative golfing.

Comment: Can the list of booleans be empty ?

Comment: @Adám : done . Ton : that is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(s.join`^`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i61LDFHo1gvKz8zLyEuQfN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0oY6CARiBGLGamlxY5Q1hCKEWjoCa/gMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 12 bytes

```java
s->s.sum()%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU@7asNAEOz1FdsY7oJ9xGn9ADeBFKmUzrhYy5I5@V7c7jkIo29XzsJOirg0DOxjZmd3WzzjrD2cBm2DjwxtrlVibRRxrNGql0Xxj2qSq1h795DMvcogEXyidnApAELaG10BMXIOZ68PYDMnSo7aHbc7wHgkOUoBvvyH4/fbgmXOy/GONTSwGmi2JkXJCjl5GxajvuyIa6t8YhWyHRsnGoUhmG5DeVpsYsSObt8IV39DFm13l/kUXkdck15K@Qy7@R1/1r@47@iLfvgB)

If a string is really required, then **20 bytes**:

```java
s->s.chars().sum()%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY27CgJBDEX7/YogCDOCg9r6ABvBwko7sYirq7POi0lGEPHb12HdThu5kJDcnJsa7zisT7dG2@AjQ51nlVgbRRzPaNVgWnxZVXIla@9@mnlXGiSCDWoHzwIgpKPRJRAj53b3@gQ2e2LLUbvL/gAYLyTbU4CdXztedQ9mn5MFVDBvaLggVV4xkpCKkhWyP2mmLbR9EJ@t8olVyAAbJyqFIZjHknKc6I1hlJVrT8o/kHGrDv2oC3gVr@YN)

The "string" answer uses the fact that a space is codepoint 32, which mod 2 returns 0.

Comment: Wow. I feel kinda stupid now ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 17 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(a)%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqrg0VyNRU9Xof0FRZl6JQppGtKGOARACyVhNLhRBQzCESkJgrOZ/AA)

Comment: This answer is not valid. given a string of space separated binary digits. and not an array

Comment: Also may I ask why did you downvote the question ? is there something wrong

Comment: @MuhammadSalman ... I guess TFeld didn't downvote it. How do you know that?

Comment: You can rollback to your original answer, the spec has been changed to allow arrays

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
OÉ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f/3Dn///RhjoGOoZgaABmGUBgLAA)

**Explanation:**

- `O`: Take the sum of the input-array
- `É`: Evaluates `sum % 2 == 1`, returning `1` if the sum is odd, `0` otherwise

---

**3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

A leading `Ç` can be added if the space-delimited string input was still mandatory, instead of a boolean-array.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cLv/4c7//w0VDBQMwdAAzDKAQAA)

- `Ç`: Push the ASCII values of all characters, and implicitly convert it to a list. `0 1` would become `[48, 32, 49]` in that case. The `O` (sum) and `É` (is odd?) will still act the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((c,d)=>c^d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5Rryg1pTQ5VUMjWSdF09YuOS5F839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrShjgEQAslYTU0uLHKGYAhVA4FAlf8B)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
so
```

Input can be a numeric vector of the form `[1 0 0 1 0]`, or a string such as `'10010'` (thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) for noticing!).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vzj///9oQwUDIASSsQA)

#### Explanation

The code is `so` simple that it hardly needs an explanation, but here it goes.

```
s    % Implicit input: numeric vector (or string). Sum of the numbers. (For string
     % input, the ASCII codes are summed. Character '1' is odd, '0' is even, and
     % space is even too, so the parity is the same as with numeric vector input)
o    % Parity. Implicit display
```

Comment: heck, this would work on a string, since `space=32` and doesn't change the parity.

Comment: Oh, good idea! My previous version used `U` to convert from string to numeric vector, but indeed it can be removed

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 44 bytes

```
A	X =X + INPUT	:S(A)
	OUTPUT =REMDR(X,2)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/35EzQsE2QkFbwdMvIDSE0ypYw1GTi9M/NATIU7ANcvV1CdKI0DHS5HL1c/n/35DLAAiBJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p040`, 10 bytes

Assumes the input list can't be empty

```perl
$\^=0+$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lJs7WQFslvrb6/39DBUMFAyA2/JdfUJKZn1f8X7fAwMQAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 41 bytes

```
b->{var r=1<0;for(var c:b)r^=c;return r;}
```

The variable r is initially set to false, since we are `XOR`ing `b[0]` with it. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##pY7BbsIwDIbP6VP42Eij2q503RugSeMyaRqSG1IUCAly3G5TlWcvCSDBAU67@Pdv2d/vLQ44265306FvrVGgLIYACzQOxkIYx5o6VBo@3z/yQLTeW40Ofj2Vl/7rOztZFyIW4oIJjJxk8GYN@wQrl0zGbdIq0ibIEyoj0yE0MLWzt3FAAmpeXp/rLrGzU/NW0qpRNWnuyQHVcRIi5YjlX2C9r3zP1SFx2boykar8lNM/cH1sZOr1E3Row1VuZlHKf/DO5rY@DLor5/RYxOkI).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
^/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9O///h9kdNa/7/jzbUUTDQUTCEIQMY1wCOYnUUolFkYgE)

-2 bytes thanks to user202729!

Comment: `OSḂ` also works.

Comment: @user202729 So it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L~,€Os2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9@nTudR0xr/YiPV////KxkqGCgYgqEBmGUAgUr/8gtKMvPziv/r6mbmFuRkJmeWAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## (Traditional) APL, 3 or 4 bytes

[TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9Ir/o/6POBfqP@qaCuP8VwAAoymWoYACEQJILVcwQDKFyEAgA), courtesy Adám

```
≠/⍎⎕
```

Analysis:

`⎕` - Accept input.
`⍎` - "unquote" it (if it's a quoted string, this will convert it to a numeric vector. If it's already a numeric vector, this is effectively a null op)
`/` - reduction - apply the operator to the left to each successive item in the vector to the right
`≠` - "not equal" - when applied strictly to boolean arguments, this is functionally identical to XOR (which is not implemented as a separate operator in APL)

If it may be assumed that the input will be a numeric vector instead of a quoted string, then the 'unquote' can be removed, saving one byte:

```
≠/⎕
```

Comment: HI. Can you kindly provide a TIO link. Thanks

Comment: I've never been able to get quad-input in APL to work at TIO, that's why I didn't do so here.

Comment: Ah I see. Oh well. Btw you can update your answer, it will be more easier now

Comment: *Input* is essentially the APL session (except that `⎕` and default output happens in *Output* and `⍞` output happens in `Debug`). For convenience, you can define your workspace in *Header*, *Code* and *Footer*, but only *Code* is counted into the char/byte count: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9Ir/o/6POBfqP@qaCuP8VwAAoymWoYACEQJILVcwQDKFyEAgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám - Thank you. I'm not sure why I was never able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 8 bytes

```
#.~+2%#@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X1mvTttIVdnh/39DBQMgBJIA)

Comment: You can use `#q~+2%` instead of `#.~+2%#@` and output via exit code to save 2 bytes. (In TIO you need to expand the debug tab if you want to see the exit code)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
r^
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=cl4=&input=WzEsMCwwLDEsMF0=)

Does exactly what it says on the tin, `r`educe the array by XORing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 11 bytes

```
i?+<^<@Oa1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z/TXtsmzsbBP9HQ5v9/QwUDBUMwNACzDCAQAA)

It's been a while, so it feels good to write a Cubix answer!

Answer (score 0):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 38 bytes

```
> Input
> 2
>> ∑1
>> 3%2
>> Output 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOwYjLzk7hUcdEQxBtrArm@peWACUVTP7/jzbUUTDQUTCEIQMY1wCOYgE)

I feel like 3 answers is too many, but I wanted to get Whispers out again. I'm still working on an XOR approach

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

Saved a few bytes with inspiration from ceilingcat.

Saved another byte thanks to Jonathan Frech

```c
r;f(char*s){for(r=0;*s;)r^=*s++;r&=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/IOk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0ijyNbAWqvYWrMozlarWFvbukjN1tC69n9uYmaehiZXNZeCQkFRZl5JmoaSakpMnpIOkGGoYACEhmBsqKSpaY1LkSEYwhSDIVh57X8A)

Comment: Can `s=r&1` not be `r&=1`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.split(' ').reduce(0){|a,b|a^b.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivuCAns0RDXUFdU68oNaU0OVXDQLO6JlEnqSYxLkmvJD8@s7b2f0FpSbFCWrS6oYIBEAJJ9VguZDFDMITKQaB67H8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Tacit prefix function.

```apl
≠/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HnAv3/aY/aJjzq7XvUN9XT/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCoYIBEAJJLgjbEAyhYhAIAA)

`/` is reduction and `≠` is XOR because XOR only gives `1` if its arguments are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
b->⊻(b...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9J1@5R126NJD09Pc3/uYkFGgVFmXklOXmPOmak6ShoRBvoGOoYAKFhrI5CtKGCgYIhGBqAWQYQGKuuqanwHwA)

`⊻` is the xor symbol, and `b...` distributes an array as individual elements before sending it to the xor function (since xor needs multiple arguments passed separately, not a single array argument).

A bit more interestingly, a version that accepts space separated (/comma-separated/unseparated) boolean values as a string, and returns the xor result :

#### Julia 0.6, 22 bytes

```julia
b->sum(Int.([b...]))%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9J1664NFfDM69ETyM6SU9PL1ZTU9Xof25igUZBUWZeSU7eo44ZaToKGkoGOoY6BkBoqKSgo6BkqGCgYAiGBmCWAQQqwaSUNDUV/gMA)